# printing just the viewpanel inside a customcontrol

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a `custom control` ( which lays on an xpage ) having some buttons and a view panel: `viewPanel1`.

I want to print JUST the data from this view panel, but not the entire window using `window.print();`.

In classic lotus notes I used: `@Command([FilePrint]; "1"; ""; ""; ""; "printview";""; "";"";"")`

Is there any possibility achieving this using javascript? I want to create a button for the printing.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: One option about printing only part of the page is CSS. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463796/how-to-only-show-certain-parts-with-css-for-print

Answer (score 2):

You need to add (or create) a stylesheet that uses `@media print`.

Here's a specific OneUI 2.1 example taken from [this XSnippet](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=oneui-2.1-print-stylesheet):

```
@media print { 
  .lotusBanner, .lotusTitleBar, .lotusColLeft, .lotusActionBar, .lotusFooter, .lotusLegal {
    display: none;
  } 
  .lotusMain, .lotusMain .lotusContent, .xspInputFieldRichText {
    border: none;
  }
  .lotusFrame {
    width: 100%;
  }
  @page { margin: 0.5cm; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. And after I create it, I just window.print() ?

Comment: Yes, which is the same as using File - Print

Comment: I will try it.. but I don't use a oneUI theme for my app

Comment: Doesn't matter if you use oneUI or not.  Look at the concept.  You add classes to the pieces of your page.  Then a rule that when printed it does not display those classes.