# Why can't I override display property applied via an asterisk?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to hide all the elements in some screen resolution and just show the wanted element to be visible:

For instance:

```
*{
    display: none;
}
#block{
    display: block !important;
}
```

But this won't override the display property anymore. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nk8np9vo/)

Comment: Did you see the demo? It's not working..

Comment: It's applying `display: none;` to the `body` element; since that's not visible, nothing inside it is visible either, regardless of what its display value is set to.

Comment: +1. That's a good question. It's a tricky thing that many people would oversee.

Comment: Even after applying display block to the body the element is not visible http://jsfiddle.net/nk8np9vo/1/

Comment: You need to apply to `html` also: http://jsfiddle.net/nk8np9vo/2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`*` targets all elements within the document, including `html` and `body` as well. That's why the content is still hidden - [verify that](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/nk8np9vo/5/).

If you want to select all elements within the `<body>` you should do that as follows:

```css
body * {
    display: none;
}

#block {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">block</div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D indeed! I just focused on the selector.

Comment: This worked out fine for me when I wanted to print just the chart.js chart on a page; which i answered via this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192878/chart-from-chart-js-to-pdf (printing just a chart using media-print).

Answer (score 1):

Because `body` and `html` are included in the universal selector `*`, which has the `display: none;` rule.

http://jsfiddle.net/nk8np9vo/6/

Comment: @C-linkNepal - [and you don't need !important](http://jsfiddle.net/yy06ra96/1/) as the style will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the target frame with your favourite DOM inspector you'll see that `<body>` remains hidden:

[image: Firebug]

Comment: @misterManSam - There're excellent explanations so far in other answers. Mine just provides a hint on how to diagnose this kind of issues.