# How to print only html contain in php code like printing receipt

Tags: javascript, php, printing

I want to print my table data `onclick`.
I use the following JavaScript code:

```
<input type="button" name="print" id="print" value="Print" onclick="myFunction()"/>

<script>
myFunction()
{
window.print();
}
</script>
```

But the code prints the entire web page.
I want to print only my table like printing a receipt how to do it?

Comment: Why not just use an `@media print` stylesheet set everything you don't want to print to `display: none;` ?

Comment: Add [print media CSS rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@media) that hide all the unnecessary/unwanted elements.

Comment: You can use css and media queries to hide content you don't want to be printed. Like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463796/how-to-only-show-certain-parts-with-css-for-print

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to use print CSS styles. In your existing CSS stylesheet, add the following section.

```
@media print {

}
```

Within `@media` block hide everything you don't want to show on print. Like this,

```
@media print {
    .classTOHide {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

`@media print` denotes the CSS styles which get applies while printing page only.

You can also attach entire stylesheet to be used while printing by using `media` attribute of `link` tag. Like this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="styles.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using JavaScript it is so easy

```
<td align="center" colspan="2">
       <input type="button" name="print" id="print" value="Print" onclick="myFunction()"/>
    </td>
```

and in script tag:-

```
<script>
function myFunction() 
{
    document.form1.print.hidden="true";
    window.print();

}
</script>
```

It will display header and footer but when browser show print preview option uncheck header-footer

Comment: and what if someone decides to print with the system dialog, rather than the button?