# Apply css only on mobile devices when printing

Tags: angular, mobile, printing

I have an angular 7 application. I want to know is there any way to write styles that is applicable on mobile devices at the time of printing only? I am not sure about whether there is a way or not. I tried with following query

```
@media print and (max-width: 599px)
```

But it is affecting printing in desktop and mobile devices. Please guide me to solve this problem.

Comment: IMO you need to define class/style for web as well, for more you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39640177/5043867

Comment: @PardeepJain Thanks to looking into this. But I am asking for applying styles when printing in only mobile devices, it should not affect desktop.